# Add png in bootstrap button like glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to replace glyphicon-user in bootstrap button with a responsive png, is there any way to do this?

```
#SignUp-btn{
width: 100% !important;
height: 45% !important;
font-size: 20px;
background-color: #262262;
border-color: #262262;
}

<div class="col-sm-6">
<a href="SignUp" class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-primary" id="SignUp-btn">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user fa-5x"></i>
<br><b> Sign Up</b>
</a>
</div>
```

[See Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOMGU.png)

Comment: No. The glyphs are stored as icon fonts. You will have to use a custom glyph, independent of the glyphicon set

Comment: you can put the image as a background image on the "i" tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put the image as a background image on the "i" tag. See sample below.

```
 #SignUp-btn + i {
        background-image: url(image.png);
        text-indent: -9999999999px;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
    }
```